# Finding automorphisms of a vector space using GAP

Tags: vector-spaces, finite-fields, coding-theory, automorphism-group, gap

**Goal:**
Given a $K$-dimensional vector space $V \subseteq \mathbb{F}_2^N$ firstly find the group $A$ of all automorphisms $\alpha_i: V\to V $ and secondly find the subgroup $\widetilde{A} \subseteq A$ of all automorphisms that are permutations.

Note: For $v=[v_0,v_1, v_2, \dots , v_N]\in V$  a permutation would be $\alpha(v)=[v_0,v_2, v_N, \dots , v_1]$. I use cycle notation which in this case is $(1,N,2)$ assuming all other $v_i$ stay in place.

**What I tried (with example):**
I am using GAP system to compute the solutions. Given a vector space $V$ from generators $g_1=[1,1,0,0]$ and $g_2=[0,0,1,1]$ I first try to find $\widetilde{A}$ by hand. There are three possible permutations $(0,1), (2,3)$ and $(0,2)(1,3)$ as well as any combination of them, so I expect $8$ elements in $\widetilde{A}$.
I construct $V$ like this:

```
g:=[[Z(2)^0, Z(2)^0, 0*Z(2), 0*Z(2)], [0*Z(2), 0*Z(2), Z(2)^0, Z(2)^0]];
V:=VectorSpace(GF(2),g);
```

Then I compute $A$ by computing all homomorphisms from $V$ to itself.

```
A:=Hom(GF(2),V,V);
```

Sadly GAP doesn't tell me the elements of $A$ but rather a string output that doesn't help much.
The number of elements is $|A|=16$.

```
A;
>>End( GF(2), <vector space of dimension 2 over GF(2)> )
Size(A);
>>16
```

I want to access the elements $\alpha_i \in A$ to further apply the constraint that $\alpha$ has to be a permutation. Furthermore $|A|$ may get large in other scenarios that I'm interested in. For those reasons I ask GAP for generators of $A$. The result is the identity mapping, a matrix homomorphism with $M_1=[[1,0],[0,0]]$ and a matrix homomorphism with $M_2=[[0,1],[1,0]]$

```
Print(GeneratorsOfAlgebra(A));
>>[ IdentityMapping( VectorSpace( GF(2), [ [ Z(2)^0, Z(2)^0, 0*Z(2), 0*Z(2) ], 
      [ 0*Z(2), 0*Z(2), Z(2)^0, Z(2)^0 ] ] ) ), 
  LeftModuleHomomorphismByMatrix( SemiEchelonBasis( VectorSpace( GF(2), 
    [ [ Z(2)^0, Z(2)^0, 0*Z(2), 0*Z(2) ], [ 0*Z(2), 0*Z(2), Z(2)^0, Z(2)^0 ] 
     ] ), [ [ Z(2)^0, Z(2)^0, 0*Z(2), 0*Z(2) ], 
      [ 0*Z(2), 0*Z(2), Z(2)^0, Z(2)^0 ] ] ), 
    [ [ Z(2)^0, 0*Z(2) ], [ 0*Z(2), 0*Z(2) ] 
     ], SemiEchelonBasis( VectorSpace( GF(2), 
    [ [ Z(2)^0, Z(2)^0, 0*Z(2), 0*Z(2) ], [ 0*Z(2), 0*Z(2), Z(2)^0, Z(2)^0 ] 
     ] ), [ [ Z(2)^0, Z(2)^0, 0*Z(2), 0*Z(2) ], 
      [ 0*Z(2), 0*Z(2), Z(2)^0, Z(2)^0 ] ] ) ), 
  LeftModuleHomomorphismByMatrix( SemiEchelonBasis( VectorSpace( GF(2), 
    [ [ Z(2)^0, Z(2)^0, 0*Z(2), 0*Z(2) ], [ 0*Z(2), 0*Z(2), Z(2)^0, Z(2)^0 ] 
     ] ), [ [ Z(2)^0, Z(2)^0, 0*Z(2), 0*Z(2) ], 
      [ 0*Z(2), 0*Z(2), Z(2)^0, Z(2)^0 ] ] ), 
    [ [ 0*Z(2), Z(2)^0 ], [ Z(2)^0, 0*Z(2) ] 
     ], SemiEchelonBasis( VectorSpace( GF(2), 
    [ [ Z(2)^0, Z(2)^0, 0*Z(2), 0*Z(2) ], [ 0*Z(2), 0*Z(2), Z(2)^0, Z(2)^0 ] 
     ] ), [ [ Z(2)^0, Z(2)^0, 0*Z(2), 0*Z(2) ], 
      [ 0*Z(2), 0*Z(2), Z(2)^0, Z(2)^0 ] ] ) ) ]
```

Now I try to construct all $16$ $\alpha_i$ from those generators and this is where I start getting confused. With three generators I can only get $2^3=8$ combinations and not $16$. Also I am not interested in homomorphisms with matrices that don't have full rank since a permutation has to be bijective. The matrix homomorphisms that fulfill the conditions use $M_0=[[1,0],[0,1]]$, $M_2=[[0,1],[1,0]]$, $M_3=[[0,1],[1,1]]$ and $M_4=[[1,1],[1,0]]$.
One can quickly verify that $M_i\cdot [g_1,g_2]$ spans the same vector space $V$ again, so they represent in fact automorphisms. However, these automorphisms are simply linear combinations of the generators and are in general not the premutations that I am looking for. A right sided matrix multiplication would be able to represent the permutations. I tried to look at the dual problem by using generators $h_i$ such that $[g_0,\dots,g_K]\cdot[h_0,\dots,h_{N-K}]^T=0$ but the vector spaces I am interested in are self dual so that doesn't work.

**Questions:**

- I can not represent some automorphisms in the form of a left sided matrix multiplication (e.g. the permutation $(0,1)$ in the example above). Instead I would need to apply a right sided matrix multiplication. How can I find these automorphisms with GAP?
- How can I directly access all elements of the automorphism group $A$ in GAP as shown in the example above?
- Why do I fail at reconstructing $A$ from it's generators as explained above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some remarks:

- you can also use `End(GF(2), V)` instead of `Hom(GF(2), V, v)` (shouldn't make a difference here, though)
- if you only want the invertible endomorphisms: those form the *unit group* of the endomorphism algebra, so:

  ```
  gap> g:=[[Z(2)^0, Z(2)^0, 0*Z(2), 0*Z(2)], [0*Z(2), 0*Z(2), Z(2)^0, Z(2)^0]];
  [ [ Z(2)^0, Z(2)^0, 0*Z(2), 0*Z(2) ], [ 0*Z(2), 0*Z(2), Z(2)^0, Z(2)^0 ] ]
  gap> V:=VectorSpace(GF(2),g);
  <vector space over GF(2), with 2 generators>
  gap> A:=End(GF(2), V);
  End( GF(2), <vector space of dimension 2 over GF(2)> )
  gap> U:=Units(A);
  <group with 2 generators>
  gap> Size(U);
  6
  ```
- this is unsurprising because $V \cong \mathbb{F}_2^2$ and hence $\mathrm{Aut}(V) \cong \mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{F}_2^2) = \mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{F}_2) \cong \mathrm{Sym}(3)$. From this you could indeed just compute the answer by hand quite easily
- to get all elements of a finite group or algebra or whatever, use `AsSet`, i.e. here: `AsSet(U)`
- your claim that you can only get `2^3` elements from 3 generators is incorrect. E.g. even a single group generator $g$ can give an infinite number of elements ($g, g^2, g^3, \dots, g^0, g^{-1}, g^{-2}, \dots$. And for two elements $g,h$ in general $gh\neq hg$, and so on.

UPDATE 2023-11-11: so it turns out you are not interested in automorphisms of the vector space $V,$ but rather in automorphisms of $\mathbb{F}_2^4$ which are induced by permutations of the coordinates and which also stabilize $V$. You can get those by defining an action of the symmetric group $S_4$ on $\mathbb{F}_2^4$ and a suitable action map, and then asking for the stabilizer:

```
gap> myAction := {V,g} -> VectorSpace(GF(2),List(Basis(V), v -> Permuted(v, g)));;
gap> S:=Stabilizer(G, V, myAction);
Group([ (1,2), (1,3)(2,4) ])
gap> Size(S);
8
gap> AsSet(S);
[ (), (3,4), (1,2), (1,2)(3,4), (1,3)(2,4), (1,3,2,4), (1,4,2,3), (1,4)(2,3) ]
```

Comment: Thanks! The only thing that remains unclear are the generators (your last bullet point). In my example $g=[[0,1],[1,0]]$ and the identity $I$ are included in the set of generators but $g\cdot g^{-1}=g\cdot g=I$. The group operation is multiplication. Why does GAP give $I$ as generator if it can be generated from $g$? That's why I thought GAP uses some other operation than the group operation to generate the group. I assumed addition. Since we are in $\mathbb{F}_2$ only $2^3$ combinations are possible because every generator is it's own additive inverse. That's where my false claim came from.

Comment: A more relevant problem that remains is that the endomorphisms are represented as left sided matrix multiplications. ```Units(End(GF(2), V))``` consists of elements that map $V$ to itself by linear combinations. This is NOT what I am interested in. Instead I am searching for endomorphisms that permute the indices of the $g_i$. These can be written as right sided matrix multiplication $G\cdot M$, where $M\in \mathbb{F}_2^{(N,N)}$ and $G$ is a matrix consisting of the $g_i$, e.g. $$
M=\begin{pmatrix}
0&1&0&0\\ 
1&0&0&0\\ 
0&0&1&0\\ 
0&0&0&1
\end{pmatrix}$$.

Comment: Whether you act on the vector space from the left or from the right is immaterial (you can switch from one to the other by transposing). Anyway, the "permutations" you ask for are *not* automorphisms of the vector space -- they only *induce* automorphisms. But multiple different of these permutations can induce the same automorphism (i.e. swapping the 1st and 2nd coordinate induces the identity, just like the trivial permutation). So if that's what you want, then asking for automorphisms of $V$ is a dead end.

Comment: Instead, take the symmetric group $S_4$, define an action map for it on $F_2^4$, then ask for the stabilizer of $V$ in it.